# extract bold and italic text from a text document

Tags: r, macos, text

I have text files and I am highlighting certain text in bold and italics. I would like a script which reads the .txt file and exports all text which is bold or italics into another document (text file).

Anyone know a way?

Preferably R solution, but can try other solutions.

Mac user

Comment: .txt files are usually plain text files lacking any formatting info e.g. italic or bold. Which file format are you using exactly?

Comment: using markdown syntax in text editor. basically my idea is to convert pdf to text to read the text book, I will bold and italicise key points of each chapter, and when I finish I want to export the key points to a sort of wiki on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a markdown formatted text file `ìn.md` and we want to create another markdown file `out.md` containing only italic and bold sections.

Content of file in.md:

```
# Header

There is *italic* and **bold** text!
There is *another italic* and **another bold** text!
```

```r
library(tidyverse)

text <- read_file("in.md")
bold_texts <- text %>%
  str_extract_all("\\*\\*[^\\*]+\\*\\*") %>%
  purrr::simplify() %>%
  map_chr(~ .x %>% str_remove_all("\\*"))
bold_texts
#> [1] "bold"         "another bold"
italic_texts <-
  text %>%
  str_remove_all(bold_texts %>% map_chr(~ paste0("\\*\\*", .x, "\\*\\*")) %>% paste0(collapse = "|")) %>%
  str_extract_all("\\*[^\\*]+\\*") %>%
  purrr::simplify() %>%
  map_chr(~ .x %>% str_remove_all("\\*"))
italic_texts
#> [1] "italic"         "another italic"

out_text <- c("#Bold texts:", bold_texts, "#Italic texts:", italic_texts) %>% paste0(collapse = "\n")
cat(out_text)
#> #Bold texts:
#> bold
#> another bold
#> #Italic texts:
#> italic
#> another italic
write_file(out_text, "out.md")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you, works perfectly!